# Combobox won't fire event on change

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, combobox

This is somewhat of a duplicate issue that I posted at
[Stop DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged Event firing on FormView command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394452/stop-dropdownlist-selectedindexchanged-event-firing-on-formview-command). Now I'm encountering these different issues.

Here I changed from Listbox (Which I would rather have) to the Combobox inside an editItemTemplate. The Combobox onSelectedIndexChanged event fires like I want when I first select an item (percent). But when I go to choose the original item (tons) it does not fire. I'm trying to recreate a toggle.

I switched to a combobox to use the SelectionChangeCommitted event. However, it's not showing up in my intellisense. I tried manually entering it and of course it didn't work at all.

My goal is to let the user enter the values as a % of the Total or actual as actual tons and then toggle back and forth. The end value that will be inserted into the DB will be in tons.

I want to either: 
a) Use the listbox and fix the issue where it won't fire the "onSelectedIndexChanged" event when submitting the form
b)Get this combobox to fire properly. I am guessing it won't unless I can get the SelectionChangeCommitted event to show up
c) A better way of going about this that I don't know of.

.aspx:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlRecycledMaterialsReceivedForm" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:FormView ID="fvAddRecycledMaterialsReceived" runat="server" SkinID="annualReportFormview" EnableViewState="false"
        HeaderText="Selected Recycled Materials Received Detail" DataKeyNames="RecycleDetailId" DefaultMode="Insert"
        DataSourceID="odsRecycledMaterialsReceivedDetail" OnDataBound="fvAddRecycledMaterialsReceived_DataBound" 
        OnItemCommand="fvAddRecycledMaterialsReceived_ItemCommand" OnItemInserted="fvAddRecycledMaterialsReceived_ItemInserted"
        OnItemUpdated="fvAddRecycledMaterialsReceived_ItemUpdated" OnItemDeleted="fvAddRecycledMaterialsReceived_ItemDeleted">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxRecycledTotalWasteQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TotalWasteQuantity") %>' Width="64px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxRecycledWasteCommercialQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CommercialQuantity") %>' Width="64px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxRecycledWasteResidentialQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ResidentialQuantity") %>' Width="64px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:ComboBox  ID="cmb_Units" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmb_Units_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Tons" Value="1" Selected />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Percent" Value="9" />
            </asp:ComboBox>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnWasteReceivedUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"
                ValidationGroup="RecycledWasteReceivedDetail" Font-Bold="True" />&nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnWasteReceivedInsertCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</asp:Panel>
```

.cs:

```
protected void cmb_Units_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tbxRecycledTotalWasteQuantity = (TextBox)fvAddRecycledMaterialsReceived.FindControl("tbxRecycledTotalWasteQuantity");
    TextBox tbxRecycledWasteResidentialQuantity = (TextBox)fvAddRecycledMaterialsReceived.FindControl("tbxRecycledWasteResidentialQuantity");
    var d_TotalWasteQuantity = Convert.ToDecimal(tbxRecycledTotalWasteQuantity.Text);
    ResidentialQuantity = Convert.ToDecimal(tbxRecycledWasteResidentialQuantity.Text);

    AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox cmb_units = (AjaxControlToolkit.ComboBox)fvAddRecycledMaterialsReceived.FindControl("cmb_units");

    if (cmb_units.SelectedIndex.ToString() == "1")
    {
        //2 = percent
        //Take tb value and convert to percent
        //300/700 * 100
        tbxRecycledWasteResidentialQuantity.Text = ((ResidentialQuantity / d_TotalWasteQuantity) * 100).ToString();
        //ResidentialQuantity = ResidentialQuantity * (d_TotalWasteQuantity / 100);
    }
    else
    {
        //Else 'tons' was chosen. Convert value(%) to tons. 
        //700 * (43/100) = 301
        ResidentialQuantity = d_TotalWasteQuantity * (ResidentialQuantity / 100);
        tbxRecycledWasteResidentialQuantity.Text = ResidentialQuantity.ToString();
        //tbxRecycledWasteResidentialQuantity.Text = "Tons";
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your Page_Load() code look like .. each change will fire a PostBack so can you show that code..?

Comment: oh.... Well the pageload is empty. I was expecting the "cmb_Units_SelectedIndexChanged" method to fire when the combobox index changed.... I understand you are telling me the Page_Load() is firing, but I am at a loss of how to get the "cmb_Units_SelectedIndexChanged" without manually calling that method in the Page_Load().

Comment: sorry, but how did u get <asp:combobox> control? b'z thr is no control like that in asp.net unless you you ajax control toolkit. which I do not see you using in your code.

Comment: at the top of my masterpage I register it as such: <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %> - Then in my "cmb_Units_SelectedIndexChanged" method I use "AjaxControlKit.ComboBox" to find the control.